# Error while building apache2 2.4.3 with mod_authnz_ldap and apr/apr-util

Tags: apache, centos, rpm, apr, mod-ldap

I'm currently trying to generate a RPM package of a patched apache2 2.4.3

I modified the httpd.spec provided with the archive, to use the SVN version of APR (version 1.4 is not provided by CentOS) :

```
%build
# forcibly prevent use of bundled apr, apr-util, pcre
rm -rf srclib/{apr,apr-util,pcre}

svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr

./buildconf
%configure \
        --enable-layout=RPM \
        --libdir=%{_libdir} \
        --sysconfdir=%{_sysconfdir}/httpd/conf \
        --includedir=%{_includedir}/httpd \
        --libexecdir=%{_libdir}/httpd/modules \
        --datadir=%{contentdir} \
        --with-installbuilddir=%{_libdir}/httpd/build \
        --enable-mpms-shared=all \
        --with-included-apr \
        --enable-suexec --with-suexec \
        --with-suexec-caller=%{suexec_caller} \
        --with-suexec-docroot=%{contentdir} \
        --with-suexec-logfile=%{_localstatedir}/log/httpd/suexec.log \
        --with-suexec-bin=%{_sbindir}/suexec \
        --with-suexec-uidmin=500 --with-suexec-gidmin=100 \
        --enable-pie \
        --with-pcre \
        --with-libxml2 \
        --enable-mods-shared=all \
        --enable-ssl --with-ssl --enable-socache-dc --enable-bucketeer \
        --enable-case-filter --enable-case-filter-in \
        --enable-session-crypto --with-crypto \
        --enable-ldap --enable-authnz-ldap --with-ldap \
        --disable-imagemap
```

The important part is :

```
        --with-included-apr \
        --enable-ldap --enable-authnz-ldap --with-ldap \
```

When I generate the package with :

```
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/httpd.spec
```

I got the following error :

```
checking for ldap support in apr/apr-util... no
configure: WARNING: apr/apr-util is compiled without ldap support
checking whether to enable mod_authnz_ldap... configure: error: mod_authnz_ldap has been requested but can not be built due to prerequisite failures
```

I found some answers on the mailing list telling about missing option `--with-ldap` which is actually present.

Comment: Do you have the openldap development package installed?  Also, when your build runs the APR configure script (separate from the main Apache one), does it say anything about detecting LDAP libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem configuring Apache2 httpd-2.4.7 in Ubuntu 13.10. You should make sure you have OpenLDAP installed. in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install sladp ldap-utils
```

In my case, that did not solve the problem so I installed the dev version:

```
sudo apt-cache search openldap #found libldap2-dev
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev
```

I think you can find the dev package in rpm using:

```
rpm -qa | grep ldap
```

And then configuring httpd using '--with-ldap' resolved the problem for me.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --sysconfdir=/etc/apache --enable-so --with-ldap --enable-ssl --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre
```